# shall we use state or props for handling inputs in redux react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am confused with props or state to use here. If I use state in @connect I get error and does not work. when I use props it does not work with onchange handler to set new props. Please help how should I make input working with state or props. I am retrieving initial data from api.

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-async-connect';
import {load, isLoaded} from 'redux/modules/overview';
@asyncConnect([{
promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState }, params: { id }, }) => {
    const promises = [];
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
        promises.push(dispatch(load(id)));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
}])
@connect(
state => ({
    overview: state.overview.data
}),
dispatch => bindActionCreators({load}, dispatch))
export default class Overview extends React.Component {
changeinput1(e) {
    this.props.overview.title = e.target.value;
    // changing value does not work here
}
constructor (props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        overview: null,
    }
}
render() {

    return (
        <div>
        <label>Input 1</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="title" name="title" maxlength="35" value={this.props.overview.title} onChange={this.changeinput1.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I also want to do validation and want to save input value on onBlur so I dont want to use form.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change reducer's(here suppose to be 'overview') value, you should define an action then dispatch it, not change it directly, the state get from store is readonly in the component

Comment: I want to get reducer value in component state but not able to get it in state with @connect

Comment: something like this @connect(
state => ({
    this.state.overview: state.overview.data
}),
dispatch => bindActionCreators({load}, dispatch))  I want overview in state of component to manipulate it in inputs

Comment: you should get the state of redux in component's props, like this.props. overview...